# Raw PCM audio playback with QPython audiostream

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, qpython

I'm trying to make a program in python, part of which will play raw pcm data. I found QPython and a library in it called audiostream. Unfortunately as soon as I call any of it's functions I get a segmentation fault.

```
import audiostream

#This causes a segmentation fault regardless of the values of parameters:
stream = audiostream.get_output(channels=2, rate=44100, buffersize=1024)
```

I'm using the default installation of QPython downloaded from the Play Store, I've changed nothing and I'm using Android 5.1.1 on OnePlus One. Why is it crashing? Do I have to do something before calling audiostream functions?

Answer (score 0):

I 've never tried audiostream before. It seems like that's not a complete module to play audio.

If you want to play audio, simply use sl4a:

```
#from androidhelper import sl4a
##qpython
#import sl4a
##qpython 3
##choose by version
droid=sl4a.Android()
mediaFile="YOUR_MEDIA_FILE_PATH"
droid.mediaPlay(mediaFile)
```

Complete sl4a API help is here: http://www.mithril.com.au/android/doc/index.html

Hope this help you!